# Validation of hurdle model?

Tags: validation, prediction

I built a hurdle model, and then used that model to predict from known to unknown data points using the predict command. Is there a way to validate the model and these predictions? Do I have to do this in two parts, for example using sensitivity and specificity for the binomial part of the model? 
Any other ideas for how to assess the validity of this model?

Answer (score 0):

For validating predictive models, I usually trust [Cross-Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

In short: With cross-validation you can measure the predictive performance of your model using only the training data (data with known results). Thus you can get a general opinion on how your model works. Cross-validation works quite well for wide variety of different models. The downside is that it can get quite computation heavy.

With large data sets, 10-fold cross-validation is enough. The smaller your dataset is, the more "folds" you have to do (i.e. with very small datasets, you have to do leave-one-out cross-validation)

With cross-validation, you get predictions for the whole data set. You can then compare these predictions to the actual outputs and measure how well your model performed.

Cross-validated results can take a bit to understand in more complicated comparisons, but for your general purpose question "how to assess the validity of the model", the results should be quite easy to use.